# Drawing a HUD above 3D with shaders in GL

Tags: opengl, shaders, hud

In the old days you would just do `glOrtho` in Projection, reset Modelview-Matrix and draw in `[-1,1],[-1,1],0`.

But now-a-days we have shaders and I wanted to avoid the use of matrices. My code so far:

```
#version 130

uniform float sizeX;
uniform float sizeY;
in vec2 position;
in vec2 coord;

out vec2 texcoord;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position = vec4(position.x * sizeX, position.y * sizeY, 0, 1);
  texcoord = coord;
}
```

Why does this not work?

If I use this instead:

```
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

The HUD is visible.

Comment: What inputs are you using?  The values in gl_Position must still be in NDC range: [-1,+1].  If your input position is supposed to be pixels, you need to properly adjust such that position 0,0 maps to -1,-1 and position WIDTH,HEIGHT maps to +1,+1 which is what the matrix from glOrtho does.

Comment: @Sean: mister, you are my hero!
i didn't test the essentials when i started and jumped straight to doing Vertex-array-nonsense.
i still doesn't do what i think it should but at least something shows. still some culling issues and and the texture repeats.. but hey, it works! can i 'vote you up' or something like that?

Comment: I guess I can make an actual answer to upvote, though I'm unsure how valuable it would be in general without rephrasing the question to be a bit less specific to your code and more about 2D and NDC coordinates in general.

Comment: "*I wanted to avoid the use of matrices.*" Um, why? Is there something wrong with matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `gl_Position` must still be in NDC range: `[-1,+1]`. If your input position is supposed to be pixels, you need to properly adjust such that position `0,0` maps to `-1,-1` and position `WIDTH,HEIGHT` maps to `+1,+1` which is what the matrix from `glOrtho` does.

Without a matrix, take any `x,y` and scale down by `2/width,2/height` then subtract `1,1` to transform to NDC.

```
gl_Position = position * vec2(2.0/sizeX,2.0/sizeY) - vec2(1,1);
```

Instead of passing those sizes each time, you could use a `vec2` uniform variable that already has `1/dim` calculated in it.